# selecting attribute records from different tables

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `carslibrary` (
  `CarID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `CarName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`CarID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `colorslibrary` (
  `ColorID` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ColorName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ColorID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `facerecord` (
  `carslibrary_ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `colorslibrary_ID` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  KEY `carslibrary_ID` (`carslibrary_ID`),
  KEY `colorslibrary_ID` (`colorslibrary_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

i want to select all records of carsLibrary and their match car colors for example

```
carID  carName  carColor
1      toyota   green
2      kia      green
3      ford     blue
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a couple of `JOIN`s:

```
SELECT `CarID`, `CarName`, `ColorName` AS CarColor FROM
  (`carslibrary` LEFT JOIN `facerecord` ON `CarID`=`carslibrary_id`)
  LEFT JOIN `colorslibrary` ON `colorslibrary_id`=`ColorID`
```